# Write a macro to check function return code

Tags: c++, error-handling

Quite common that we have to call set of functions that have similar behavior - for example return negative value and set `errno` variable in case of failure. Instead of repeatedly write check code, sometimes it is useful to wrap it into macro:

```
#define CHECKED_CALL( func, ... ) \
    do {\
        auto ret = func( __VA_ARGS__ );\
        if( ret < 0 ) {\
            std::cerr << #func "() failed with ret " << ret << " errno " << errno << std::endl;\
            throw std::runtime_error( #func "()" failed" );\
         }\
    while(false)
```

then use is simple:

```
 CHECKED_CALL( func1, 1, 2, 3 );
 CHECKED_CALL( func2, "foobar" );
```

etc. Now let's say I need to get result of the call in case it did not fail. Something like:

```
 auto r = CHECKED_CALL( func3, 1.5 );
```

Obviously this would not work as written and of course I can write another macro, but question is, is it possible to write macro that would work in both cases? Or maybe not macro but not very complicated code, that will take me 10 times more time to implement than to write yet another macro for value return. Especially not to generate warning of unused code etc.

Comment: in c++ you should write inline functions instead, you can overload those

Comment: Problem with inline function - it would be overly complicated to write generic one, as how to pass function name, and all arguments. Macro is very simple solution. If you mean I will have to overload each separate function with checked wrapper, this is pretty much the same as call every one with check.

Comment: No, it's not complicated at all. That's what templates are for. And they'll end up doing pretty much the same thing as an old-style macro, except with full type-safety and access to all of core C++ features.

Comment: Is there a way to perform the stringification the macro does in a template? [My attempt](https://godbolt.org/z/M6q1jW85E) at implementing this as a template relies on the slightly ugly hack of passing a function name as an argument.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "No, it's not complicated at all." sure, why you do not post an example as an answer?

Comment: @NathanPierson I think we can merge your solution with simple macro just for stringification and that would be very good if not perfect answer. Can you post your answer? I do not see a point to eliminate macro at any cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything in your `CHECKED_CALL` macro can be turned into a function template, which has the advantage of passing through the C++ compiler's type system instead of the preprocessor's brute textual substitution.

So, for instance, we can write

```cpp
template<class Callable, class... Args>
void checked_call(Callable t_callable, std::string t_functionName, Args&&... t_args)
{
    auto ret = t_callable(std::forward<Args>(t_args)...);
    if( ret < 0 ) 
    {
    std::cerr << t_functionName << "() failed with ret " << ret << " errno " << errno << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error( t_functionName + "() failed" );
    }
}
```

One downside here is that `checked_call` requires us to explicitly pass a `std::string` representing the name of a function.

Example calling code:

```cpp
int failingFunction()
{
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    checked_call(failingFunction, "failingFunction");
}
```

We can introduce a macro that automatically pairs a function with a string representation of its name to use with `checked_call`, like so:

```cpp
#define NAMED_FUNCTION(func) func, #func

int main(){
    checked_call(NAMED_FUNCTION(failingFunction));
}
```

We could also adapt the definition of `checked_call` to return `ret` if we wanted to, by changing the return type from `void` to `auto` and adding a `return ret;` if it doesn't throw. However, you may need to examine your functions' actual signature to figure out where the true return value is, assuming the nominal return value is actually an error code.

Comment: Or `#define CHECKED_CALL( function, ... ) checked_call( function, #function, __VA_ARGS__ )` instead

Comment: "assuming the nominal return value is actually an error code" no you cannot get error code as return value - exception would be thrown and return will never happen. Intention is to use it with something lilke `::open()` system function which returns -1 in error, but actual value otherwise.

Comment: If the idea is to use it with a function where `ret < 0` represents an error that should be turned into an exception and `ret >= 0` represents a genuine return value, `return ret;` at the end of `checked_call` seems like what you want.

Comment: I know, I mean you may want to put it into your answer, as it is not only for me.